# Flex warning Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "layout"

Tags: flash, apache-flex, layout, data-binding

I got some code:

```
...
<fx:Declarations>
<s:Animate id="toRight"   target="{cp.layout}">
<s:SimpleMotionPath property="horizontalScrollPosition"                                     valueFrom="{cp.layout.horizontalScrollPosition}" valueTo="{cp.layout.horizontalScrollPosition+42}"/>
            </s:Animate>
</fx:Declarations>
....
....
<s:List id="cp" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"  itemRenderer="com.mRenderer" horizontalCenter="1" verticalCenter="1" change="changeEvt(event)" borderAlpha="0"  width="458" height="65"   initialize="initList();"  >
```

.....

I use that animation for smoothing move with arrows in my List.

But I got some warnings:

> **Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "layout".**

I know layout not bindable in List. but its not custom class. How  can I prevent that?

Comment: It's simple i just place 2 arrows-buttons and use that animation to smooth scrolling in that List(i need easing for scrolling).All works fine. But i need remove that warnings.

Answer (score 1):

So you're using the `Animate` effect to animate the `horizontalScrollPosition` of the layout object? And I assume that is working correctly.

The warning you get is triggered by this curly brace binding expression: `target="{cp.layout}"`. The warning is telling you that the `List` control does not dispatch any binding events if it's `layout` property changes. So if something in your app changes the list's layout, your animation effect will stop working.

That's just a warning, and as long as you don't expect to change the layout, your code should work just fine.

If you'd like to make the warning disappear, you have three options:

- Update your compiler settings so that this warning does not get generated (bad idea)
- Instead of using a property that is not bindable in your curly brace expression, use a function call that returns the non-bindable property.
- Use a "creationComplete" event handler to assign the `target` property of the animation

**Example of using a function in a binding expression:**

```
<s:Animate target="{getAnimationTarget()}" />

private function getAnimationTarget():Object
{
    return cp.layout;
}
```

While the same problem can occur (if the list's layout changes, no event will be dispatched by the list to update the binding), the above syntax should prevent the warning from being generated. The Flex compiler doesn't generate this warning, by design, when the curly brace expression includes a function call.

**Example of using the "creationComplete" event of the `List`:**

```
<s: List creationComplete="myFunction() />

private myFunction()
{
    toRight.target = cp.layout;
}
```

Comment: I tried use a function call  as you write. Warning dissapear but animation doesnt work.Any idea why?

Comment: @user2381360 it could be a timing issue. In the function, check to see if cp.layout is null. Or you could make the assignment using a creationComplete event handler on the List: `<s: List creationComplete="myFunction() />` and `private myFunction() { toRight.target = cp.layout; }`